# Does there exist a Babel like compiler for Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, aspectj, javassist, cglib

With javascript if we want to make sure that our code runs in all browser versions we can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).  Is there something like this for Java, where we could write our code in Java 9, but it will run in a Java 6 runtime?

For example can Kotlin target multiple JVM runtime versions?

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Comment: Not sure why all the downvotes, it's a legit exception to the rule of thumb that @RobertColumbia pointed to: since Java (unlike Javascript) is statically typed, what you want to check is that your code *compiles* both for Java 6 as well as Java 9. Well, lucky you :) Java 9's compiler has flags that allow you to either get warnings or break based on compatibility. For more info see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-6FB24439-342C-496E-9D99-5F752528C7B1

Comment: @alfasin even if your code compiles in both versions, how do you know that it does the same things?

Comment: @RobertColumbia there's this thing call regression testing and unit tests ...

Comment: @Ole I know that.

Comment: First of all I'm not asking for a recommendation.  I'm asking if anyone knows whether something like Babel exists for Java - because it would end the endless debates that organizations like Apache groups, etc. have WRT upgrading java for the project - it's a binary question - not a recommendation question.  Just because Google does not see it, does not mean it does not exist.

Comment: Wikipedia to the rescue: ["Java backporting tools"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_backporting_tools)

Comment: Aha!  So there are some out there!  See guys - was that so hard?

Comment: I was hoping for something like Kotlin to target multiple JVM runtimes - I guess we just have to dream for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I was hoping for something like Kotlin to target multiple JVM runtimes - I guess we just have to dream for now.

You can compile Kotlin code to JDK6, JDK7, JDK8, JDK9 or any JDK above JDK6. This is what meant by supporting Java 1.6 level byte code. All features of Kotlin will stay the same, except for libraries, which can require different JDK versions.

The byte code generated by Kotlin will generally stay the same independent of the target JVM version. An exception is if you set a compiler option `jvmTarget = "1.8"`, then the compiler may (or may not) use some features of JDK8 as an optimization.

IMHO this question got all the minuses because of how unexpected it is. Tools like Babel are unique to JavaScript because in all other languages they are called compilers. Since JS decided it could do without a compiler, I has such problems with deployments. There are (very limited) back porting tools for Java, but they are just plugins to the compiler. Kotlin doesn't have any, because its development is independent of JDK and it has to support all previous JDK versions above 1.6.

To sum it up, if you use Kotlin for JVM or JS development, your dream have come true - you can use any version of Kotlin, with any JVM library, probably any JS library above ES5.1, and get consistent runtime representation.

Answer (score 1):

There is an unofficial library `retrolambda` which compiles `Java 8` feature `lambda expression` into `Java 6`(just like Babel).

> I guess you will enjoy it, and here it is: https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda

Answer (score 1):

You can check teaVM ! http://teavm.org/ also there is dukeScript